# Different time (day) of last message shown in room info and in list of rooms

Tags: bug, chat, timestamps

I have noticed that when I looked on the [info for a chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9369/mathoverflow), it shown that the last message was posted 8 days ago. But in the [list for rooms for that site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=mathoverflow.net), the same room was displayed with the information, that the last message was posted 9 days ago.

The screenshots below were taken within a minute of each other, and when I display the room and the list of room at this moment, the situation is still the same.

[image]

[image]